# Как установить промежуток времени?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Только начинаю работать со временем. Решил использовать moment.js. Дошел до момента, с которым разобраться не смог. Есть работа магазина (в разные дни с разным графиком, в понедельник и среду он работает с 08:00 до 13:00, а в четверг и пятницу с 12:00 до 17:00). Решил сделать так:

```
               var now = moment().format('HH:mm');
               var time1 = moment(now, 'HH:mm').isAfter('08:00');
               var time2 = moment(now, 'HH:mm').isBefore('14:00');
               if (time1 < now < time2) {
                  console.log(now);
               }
```

В дальнейшем при запросе пользователя должно проверяться то время, которое у пользователя сейчас, если оно входит в период графика работы, то будет высвечиваться, что магазин работает, или наоборот не работает. Остальная часть кода рабочая, а вот как сделать условия времени, пока не понял. До этого пробоал через node-cron, не выходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `moment(now, 'HH:mm').isAfter('08:00')` возвращает `true` или `false`
Соответственно вам просто нужно чтобы обе проверки возвращали `true` это и будет временем работы магазина

```
if (time1 && time2) {
  console.log(now);
}
```