# Как учитывать время между 2 моментами?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Необходимо, чтобы в определенные дни в определенное время выдавалось сообщение, что интернет-магазин работает, если время не это - не работает. Сообщение выдается, только moment.js не учитывает день недели, он считает только время между 8ч и 17, а так же между 18 и 23ч ежедневно по МСК времени. Как исправить?

```
var now = moment().tz("Europe/Moscow").format("dddd HH:mm");
var day1 = moment().day("Monday");
var day2 = moment().day("Tuesday");
var day3 = moment().day("Wednesday");
var day4 = moment().day("Thursday");
var day5 = moment().day("Friday");
var day6 = moment().day("Saturday");
var day7 = moment().day("Sunday");
const timeDay = moment(now, "dddd HH:mm").isBetween({ hour: 08, minute: 00 }, { hour: 17, minute: 00 });
const timeNight = moment(now, "dddd HH:mm").isBetween({ hour: 18, minute: 00 }, { hour: 23, minute: 00 });
if ((day1 || day 2) & timeDay )
```

Comment: Вам нужно, что сообщение появлялось в Понедельник и Вторник с 8 до 17 и с 18 до 23, а все остальные дни его не было, верно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как установить промежуток времени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1514397/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)